# I am not correctly reading from the text file into an ArrayList after parsing each line into an object

Tags: java

I am trying to read from the txt file and then parse through it and make each line a new object in an ArrayList. I keeps telling me its null and I cannot figure out why. I have not used java in a long time so I'm sure its dumb.

```
 public class AccessibilityTest {
      private String cat;
      private String googErr;
      private String waveErr;
      private String sortErr;
      private String lintErr;
      private String desc;
    
      public AccessibilityTest(String cat,String googErr,String waveErr,String sortErr,String lintErr, String desc){
        this.cat = cat;
        this.googErr = googErr;
        this.waveErr = waveErr;
        this.sortErr = sortErr;
        this.lintErr = lintErr;
        this.desc = desc;
      }
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccessibilityResults.readTxtFile("a11yCheckersResults.txt");//this is one place im getting the error and its me trying to target that txt file
        System.out.println();
      }
    
      public String getCategory() {
        return cat;
      }
      public String getGoogleResult() {
        return googErr;
      }
      public String getWaveResult() {
        return waveErr;
      }
      public String getSortsiteResult() {
        return sortErr;
      }
      public String getAslintResult() {
        return lintErr;
      }
      public String getDescription() {
        return desc;
      }
    
      @Override
      public String toString(){
        return "fsdfse"+ getCategory() + getGoogleResult()+ getWaveResult()+ getSortsiteResult() + getAslintResult() + getDescription();
      }
    }
```

This is the other file where I am actually parsing through the txt file and creating the objects.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class AccessibilityResults {
      
      private static ArrayList<AccessibilityTest> list;
    
      public AccessibilityResults() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
      }
    
      public static void readTxtFile(String fileName){
        try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName))){
          while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            String cat = reader.next();
            String err1 = reader.next();
            String err2 = reader.next();
            String err3 = reader.next();
            String err4 = reader.next();
            String desc = reader.nextLine();
            list.add(new AccessibilityTest(cat, err1, err2, err3, err4,desc));//this is one spot im getting the error
    
          }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.out.println("File not found: " + fileName);
        }`enter code here`
      }
    }
    
    //txt file
    
    //a11yCheckersResults.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `list` and `readTxtFile` is **static** method,but the `readTxtFile()` that init `list` is not `static`,and in java `static` properties and method will be inited before none `static` which cause it

To solve it,there are several options:
one option is just to remove all the `static` in `list` and `readTxtFile()`,another options is just init `list` when declare it `private static ArrayList<AccessibilityTest> list = new ArrayList<>();`

```
  // static
  private static ArrayList<AccessibilityTest> list;

  // no static,so list will always be null
  public AccessibilityResults() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
  }

 // static
  public static void readTxtFile(String fileName){
    try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(fileName))){
      while(reader.hasNextLine()){
        String cat = reader.next();
        String err1 = reader.next();
        String err2 = reader.next();
        String err3 = reader.next();
        String err4 = reader.next();
        String desc = reader.nextLine();
        list.add(new AccessibilityTest(cat, err1, err2, err3, err4,desc));//this is one spot im getting the error

      }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("File not found: " + fileName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @NathanWaters you need to use `new AccessibilityResults().readTxtFile()` instead

Comment: or simply just create an instance of `AccessibilityResults`

Comment: @NathanWaters but you can accept my answer?